# Not able to access Nexus console on my Ubuntu VM instance in GCP

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, nexus, nexus3

I have installed Nexus (as a service) on my Ubuntu VM instance and while creating the vm instance, I have also checked "Allow HTTP traffic" and "Allow HTTPS traffic" options.

When I do a `$ tail -f /opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/log/nexus.log`, I see that Nexus is running:

```
2021-07-30 06:20:10,046+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@73ded096{Sonatype Nexus,/,file:///opt/nexus/public/,AVAILABLE}
2021-07-30 06:20:10,099+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@5bb22683{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2021-07-30 06:20:10,100+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @48575ms
2021-07-30 06:20:10,101+0000 INFO  [jetty-main-1]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jetty.JettyServer - 
-------------------------------------------------

Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.32.0-03

-------------------------------------------------
```

When I do a : `$ sudo netstat -pnltu | grep -i "8081"`, I see:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11722/java
```

Also, a `$ sudo systemctl status nexus` :

```
● nexus.service - nexus service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nexus.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-07-30 06:19:21 UTC; 27min ago
   Main PID: 11722 (java)
      Tasks: 71 (limit: 4710)
     Memory: 1011.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nexus.service
             └─11722 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -server -Dinstall4j.jvmDir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre -Dexe4j.moduleName=/opt/nexus/>

Jul 30 06:19:21 ubuntu-nexus systemd[1]: Starting nexus service...
Jul 30 06:19:21 ubuntu-nexus nexus[11541]: Starting nexus
Jul 30 06:19:21 ubuntu-nexus systemd[1]: Started nexus service.
```

But, When I try to access the Nexus console through the vm instance's external ip with nexus' port-> `http://34.xxx.xx.xxx:8081/`
I am not able to access it (This site can’t be reached).

Is there any firewall settings in GCP, that needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Allow HTTP traffic" and "Allow HTTPS traffic" only open port 80 and 443, while Nexus is listening on port 8081. Either change the listening port or open port 8081

Answer (score 0):

As per @Martheen's answer above, I created

1. A firewall rule > [opened port](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/) 8081
2. Applied the rule to my VM instance (by mentioning the rule tag in the network section)

Worked like a charm!